# What is the minimum speed for convergence?

Tags: real-analysis

I've read several passages that state things like 'the function doesn't decrease fast enough and hence doesn't converge'. How fast is fast enough?

So far the only explanation I've found is basically to compare the line $y=e^{-x}$ to $y=5$. The line $y=e^{-x}$ will converge to zero (as $x$ increases to infinity) while the line $y=5$ won't. I get the idea but it doesn't tell me anything about what the 'speed' should be, or how to measure it.

Comment: Can you be a little more descriptive? Convergence can mean many things. Both of your functions $y=e^{-x}$ and $y=5$ "converge" as $x\to\infty$ and I'd argue that $y=5$ does so "better" since its always closer to it's limit.

Comment: I'd love to but that's usually how the statement is presented. An example would be: 'The moments of a Cauchy distribution don't exist because the tails don't decrease fast enough'.

Answer (score 1):

A function $f(x)$ can decrease extremely slowly and still converge to zero as $x \to \infty.   f(x)=\frac 1{\log(\log(x))}$ would be an example.  You need a function to decrease quickly (faster than $\frac 1x$) if you want its integral to converge.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why it needs to decrease faster than $1/x$?

Comment: Because $\frac 1x$ integrates to $\log x$ which does not converge.  Any higher negative exponent, $x^{-p}$ integrates to $x^{-p+1}$ which goes to zero.

Answer (score 0):

There is no minimum speed since, for every function $f$ such that $f(x)\to0$ there exists another function $g$ much larger in the sense that $\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}\to0$, such that $g(x)\to0$ as well.

Likewise, for every function $f$ whose integral converges at $+\infty$, there exists another function $g$ much larger in the sense that $\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}\to0$, whose integral also converges at $+\infty$.

Likewise, for every convergent series $\sum\limits_nx_n$, there exists another convergent series $\sum\limits_ny_n$ whose entries are much larger in the sense that $\dfrac{x_n}{y_n}\to0$ when $n\to\infty$.